# lectura / escritura mp4 metadatos en Android

Tags: android

Quiero leer y editar ( escritura) a los metadatos mp4 . En particular, quiero leer / escribir etiquetas de metadatos en Android como se muestra en la imagen siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busqué esto en Internet y encontré mp4Parser , pero creo que no escriba mp4Parser Título de palabras clave .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El SDK Android contiene la clase **[MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)** con la cual podemos obtener los meta datos dentro de un archivo, puede leer más acerca de las constantes que definen cada metadata [aquí](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) :

```
  public void readMetaData(){
       File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       File  file = new File(sdcard,"/Android/data/miarchivo.mp4");

        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Existe el archivo .mp4");

            //Clase agregada en API 10
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            try {
                retriever.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
                    if(retriever.extractMetadata(i)!=null) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Metadata :: " + retriever.extractMetadata(i));
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "NO Existe el archivo .mp4");
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para escribir o editar metada, El SDK de android no cuenta con algún método, probablemente por motivos de copyright, pero puedes usar opciones como:

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

http://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java